# Oracle instant client 10 : ODBC: ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 127 ,

Tags: oracle, powerbi, odbc

Specifically when referring to it through PowerBI; either when refreshing from DataHub or from the desktop version from Windows Server 2019. This happens on and off.Have checked my registry to make exact match to the path where it is installed C:\Oracle\Ora10B ; my environment PATH includes the address with exact same format.
I have unistalled and reinstalled, and first time try the connection through PowerBI works and all of the sudden fails.

All connections work when testing/accessing from the ODBC64.

Comment: Maybe you missed 32bit vs. 64bit versions.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, sure about is  the right version . I have an old version of ORacle 8i, and instant client 10 is the only one available to log into. My services had been pretty steady, and just recently started to happen.